# React-Native: Dynamically add navigationOptions from tab screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have created react-native app having stackNavigator, drawerNavigator and tabnavigator same as given [here](https://readybytes.in/blog/how-to-integrate-tabs-navigation-drawer-navigation-and-stack-navigation-together-in-react-navigation-v2).

But i am not able to dynamically set title for header.

How to dynamically add header title using navigationOptions?

In above link example - how to add navigationOptions in About, Home or Contact screen to set header title.

Or is there any way to call function from Appnavigator which is defined in any of tab screen i.e, About, Home or contact.